# How to find a solution for a matrix with 1 equation and 3 unknown variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The task is to find all solutions for $A_1 x = 0$ with $x\in \mathbb R^3$

$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3 & -9 \\
2 & 1 & -3 \\
-4 & -2 & 6 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The given solution is as follows:
$$L_1 = \{ \lambda \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix} + \mu \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} | \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb R \}$$

As far as I understand the matrix has 3 unkowns and only 1 equation resulting in: 
$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

My approach was to find a way to display the soltions by rearranging $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ in dependancy to each other, which results in:

$$L_1 = \{x =  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{3x_3-x_2}{2} \\ 3x_3-2x_1 \\ \frac{2x_1 + x_2}{3} \end{pmatrix} \space | \space x \in \mathbb R^3\}$$

I tried searching for a similar problem but usually there are at least two equations for three unknowns resulting in one free to choose and the others depending on the one chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you can represent the solutions of the linear equation 
$$2x_1+x_2-3x_3=0$$ 
as
$$L_1 = \left\{x =  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{3x_3-x_2}{2} \\ 3x_3-2x_1 \\ \frac{2x_1 + x_2}{3} \end{pmatrix} \space | \space x \in \mathbb R^3\right\}.$$
You may write for example,
$$L_1 = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} \frac{3x_3-x_2}{2} \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix} \space | x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
=\{ x_2 \mathbf{u} + x_3 \mathbf{v} | x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
where 
$$ \mathbf{u}=(-1/2,1,0)^t\quad\mathbf{v}=(3/2,0,1)^t.$$
Similarly
$$L_1 = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ 3x_3-2x_1 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix} \space | \space x \in \mathbb R^3\right\}
=\{ x_1 \mathbf{u} + x_3 \mathbf{v} | x_1, x_3 \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
where 
$$ \mathbf{u}=(1,-2,0)^t\quad\mathbf{v}=(0,3,1)^t.$$
The set of all solutions of the given equation is a vector space of dimension $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. We find two linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{u}$, and $\mathbf{v}$ which satisfy the equation and the set of solutions can be written as
$$L_1 = \{ \lambda \mathbf{u} + \mu \mathbf{v} | \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R} \}.$$